# correction required for regular expression to get site name

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Problem: Extraction anything between `http://www.` and `.com` OR `http://` & `.com`.

Solution:

```
<?php
$url1='http://www.examplehotel.com';
//$url2='http://test-hotel-1.com';
$pattern='@^http://([^/]+).com@i';
preg_match($pattern, $url1, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

When $url1 is matched it should return string 'examplehotel'
when $url2 is matched it should return string 'test-hotel-1'

It works correctly for $url2 but empty for $url1....

In my pattern I want to add `[http://]` or `[http://www.]` I added `(http://)+(www.)+` but the match returns are not expected :(.

May I know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
$pattern='@^http://(?:www\.)?([^\.]+).com@i';
```

or in your pattern you just need to make `www` optional (may or may not appear in pattern):

```
$pattern='@^http://(?:www\.)?([^/]+).com@i';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you are matching everything from the two slashes to the `.com`. If there is a `www.` you are matching this too, within your capturing group.

The solution is to match `www.` optionally before your capturing group, like this

```
^http://(?:www\.)?([^/]+)\.com
        ^^^^^^^^^^       ^^
```

`(?:www\.)?` This is a non capturing group, i.e. the content is not stored in the result. The `?` at the end makes it optional.

`\.` will match a literal ".". `.` is a special character in regex and means "Any character".

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ufde), When you hover your mouse over the strings, you will see the content of the capturing group.

Regarding your tries with `[http://]` and so on. When you use square brackets, then you are creating a character class, that means match one of the characters from inside the brackets. When you want to group the characters, then use a capturing `()` or a non capturing `(?:)` group.

Comment: +1 this clearly helped me to understand where I was wrong. Thanks Stema

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('%http(?:s)?://(?:www\.)?(.*?)\.com%i', $url, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($result[1])
```